# How to start my text from first in custom environment using enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate

I am unable start my text from 1. it always leave blank in 1., it starts from 2.
below is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{xstring}
 \newcommand{\true}{Yes}
 \IfStrEq{\true}{Yes}{
 \newcommand{\custom}[1]{
 \noindent\textbf{List:}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item #1
 \end{enumerate}
 }
 }{}




 \begin{document}
 \custom{
 \item A
 \item B
 \item C
 }
 \end{document}
```

Here is the output of the above MWE
[image]

Comment: Just replace `\item #1` for `#1` in your custom definition.

Comment: Thank you so much @AndreyL.